# Make other process handle SIGTERM properly

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix

I have some program, that I would like to run under supervision system. When program it to be stopped, it is sent `SIGTERM` signal, and, after some timeout, `SIGKILL` signal. My issue is that program exits *ungracefully* on `SIGTERM` -- it uses default handler.

Neither changing supervision system nor the program is option for me. I consider writing some kind of wrapper, that would fork the program, catch `SIGTERM` and request graceful exit in it, something in lines of this pseudo-C:

```
// wrapper.c
setsid();
signal(SIGTERM, &make_child_exit_gracefully);
pid = fork() ? waitpid(pid) : exec("/sbin/naughty-program");
```

Problem with that approach, that if `naughty-program` some-why reject request for graceful exit, `SIGKILL` from supervision system would kill wrapper, but program will just receive `SIGHUP`, which it can ignore. This way, I can end with wild `naughty-program`, re-parented to PID1 instead of being killed.

Is there more reliable solution? Is it possible to somehow inject non-trivial code to child process to be used as signal handler? Is it possible to map `naughty-program` into address space of wrapper and transmit control to it?

Ideally, I am looking for POSIX-compliant solution, although Linux-specific is fine too.

Comment: What does "make the program exit gracefully" mean?  If the program handles SIGTERM explicitly, that's probably what you want.  But if it doesn't, you can't make it do so except by modifying the (other) program.  There isn't a POSIX way to do it AFAIK.  I don't think there's a reliable Linux way to do it, though I suppose you could try force-loading some DLL (via `LD_PRELOAD`) which provides a mechanism of some sort that sets the signal handler for SIGTERM to do something vaguely appropriate. But it is extremely icky — for use only in dire emergencies. I trust your code isn't exactly as shown.

Comment: Program uses default `SIGTERM` handler, while graceful exit is triggered only by writing command to controll pipe (or stdin, or socket, it is configurable).

Comment: For the most part, I think you're out of luck.  Have you checked how the command reacts to SIGHUP?  Or any other signals?  Maybe it is programmed to handle one or more of them and exit gracefully.  If it isn't (as is quite likely, I think), then you're probably out of luck.  By all means wait for others to respond; if they say different, they may be right.